# If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure, is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in E: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>0\})=0$?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

**Definition**. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $E\in\mathcal{M}$. Let $f:E\to\Bbb R$ and $f_n:E\to\Bbb R$ be measurable functions for all $n\in \Bbb R$. We say that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure provided $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in E: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

**Question**. We know that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in E: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>0\})=0$ then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure. How about the converse? If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure then
$$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\cup_{m=1}^\infty E_{m,n})\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty}\mu(E_{m,n}))$$
where $E_{m,n}=\{x\in E:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{m}\}$ for $m,n\in \Bbb N$.

1. Could we interchange the limit here?
2. If the converse is not true, could anyone give a counter example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about $f_n=1/n$, then it converges to $f=0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ thus in measure, but $|f_n(x)-f(x)|>0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$, so the converse is false